# Connection to Globalscape EFT ssh server from RHEL8 fails with "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: linux, ssh, redhat-enterprise-linux, windows-server-2016

I am attempting to connect from RHEL8 to a Windows 2016 Server using Globalscape EFT as ssh service.

```
[acoder@rhel8]# ssh RemoteUser@globalscape.eft.server
EFT Login - %DATE% %TIME% - Please enter valid credentials to continue RemoteUser@globalscape.eft.server: Permission denied (publickey).
[acoder@rhel8]#
```

I've confirmed with the EFT server admin that the md5sum of the id_rsa.pub file they used to import to Globalscape EFT matches my own id_rsa.pub. Our kex, cipher, and mac have matches as well.

Full verbose output from the failed ssh connection (as seen from my end):

```
[acoder@rhel8]# ssh -v RemoteUser@globalscape.eft.server
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug1: FIPS mode initialized
debug1: Connecting to vrdownload.dph.ga.gov [3.141.217.44] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/acoder/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.0
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version 1.82_sshlib Globalscape
debug1: no match: 1.82_sshlib Globalscape
debug1: Authenticating to vrdownload.dph.ga.gov:22 as 'RemoteUser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes256-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: kex: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 need=32 dh_need=32
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(2048<8192<8192) sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: got SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:1WnR3yBUoA62gpUpvV3v8s5xCiz5fLFhbw42pKdOVjQ
debug1: Host 'vrdownload.dph.ga.gov' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/acoder/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ro17/srlJ4pU8V169VdnHYqpGBI6ZZPUUQOEExrmOHs
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
EFT Login - %DATE% %TIME% - Please enter valid credentials to continuedebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:ro17/srlJ4pU8V169VdnHYqpGBI6ZZPUUQOEExrmOHs
debug1: send_pubkey_test: no mutual signature algorithm
debug1: Trying private key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/acoder/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
RemoteUser@globalscape.eft.server: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Checking format of my pub key:

```
# ssh-keygen -l -f id_rsa.pub 
3072 SHA256:ro17/srlJ4pU8V169VdnHYqpGBI6ZZPUUQOEExrmOHs root@nbs (RSA)
```

1. Should my id_rsa.pub file be exported to a different format for them to use with EFT?
2. Anything else I could try to get my pub key to successfully import to Globalscape EFT?